# Remove merge branch MERGE_MSG message when using Git pull on server remote repository

Tags: git, github

I know `git pull` is equal to `git fetch` and then `git merge`. When I use `git pull origin dev` from my remote repository on the server, to merge the latest updates into my website, I see this message:

```
Merge branch 'dev' of https://github.com/jaimemontoya/jaimemontoya into dev
# Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
# especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
#
# Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts
# the commit.
```

It was not always popping up. I do not remember when exactly it started to happen, and I do not understand why. I do not like that message because when I use `git pull origin dev` I know what I am doing and I do not need the extra step of pressing `Ctrl + X` to save changes and exit. How can I get rid of that message?

[image]

UPDATE 1: Before using `git pull origin dev` from the server, I had already used from Git in my local computer, the following sequence: `git add .`, then `git commit -m "My commit message."`, and finally `git push origin dev`. So at this point, when I use `git pull origin dev` from the server where my website is hosted, I should already have the corresponding commit message. But I guess the system is asking for a special commit message exclusive to the merge commit operation.

I am not interested in specifying a commit message for my merge operations triggered by `git pull origin dev`. I just want to merge without commit message, hence not having that popup message requesting for me to enter a commit message. Is it possible to merge without receiving that popup that requires to enter a merge commit message?